# Internet Explorer save file location

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer, windows-registry, internet-explorer-11

Background:
We use a Remote Desktop / Terminal Server for our ERP application.  It integrates with SQL SRS to generate reports.  Reports are viewed in our ERP application, but are actually IE windows integrated into he ERP application.

When a user wants to save a report, they may do so.  It brings up the IE save-as dialog box.  What we would like to be able to do is bypass that dialog box, and force the location to a network share for them.  We want to take away their ability to choose the location.  Or, at the least, we want to force the default location to that network share.

Does anyone know how to do this?  Preferably with Group Policy, or at the worst a single Registry setting in HKLM.

Thanks!

Comment: If the program could handle it, that would be best. You would place the URL in the trusted sites zone and relax the permissions so that it could more tightly control the browser. Have you consulted with the software vendor? Apart from that, I know the following link is old, but you could hide all those other locations with group policy like described here: https://www.teamsoftwaresolutions.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17

Comment: Unfortunately, most of that solution was specifically for "PWB".  As the save dialog is an IE engine wrapped inside our ERP app, it is IE that needs to be affected -- it is not using our ERP system to save files, it is using IE.  The GP options given help remove some options from Save As dialogs, but do not lock a user into only being able to save to a predetermined location.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But hiding/restricting where the user can save to also helps to accomplish what you are requesting. It may be all you have to work with. Talking to the software vendor should be the first step. They might have an answer for this already.